# How to make footer stick to the bottom then resizing?

Tags: html, css

How to make footer stick 45px at the bottom and stick to the same distance when resizing page? I tried many things but footer still in the same position.

How it look like now :

[image]

How it should be :

[image]

This is code snippet what i done so far:

**HTML**

```
<section id="footer">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 left-col">
                        <p><a class="contacts" href="#">CONTACTS</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 contact-person">
                        <h2>STUART LAWSON</h2>
                        <p>20 7409 8920</p>
                        <p>07870 555 930</p>
                        <p><a class="email" href="#">slawson@savills.com</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 contact-person">
                        <h2>JOSH LAMB</h2>
                        <p>020 7409 8891</p>
                        <p>07976 988 486</p>
                        <p><a class="email" href="#">jlamb@savills.com</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 contact-person">
                        <h2>SAM BOREHAM</h2>
                        <p>020 7710 7963</p>
                        <p>07917 635 465</p>
                        <p><a class="email" href="#">samb@gmreal.com</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 contact-person">
                        <h2>DAN ROBERTS</h2>
                        <p>020 7710 7963</p>
                        <p>07801 143 909</p>
                        <p><a class="email" href="#">danr@gmreal.com</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 right-col">
                        <h2><a class="info" href="#">info@theriverbuilding.com</a></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

**CSS**

```
.col-md-2 {

}

#footer {
    padding: 100px 45px 0;
}

.left-col {
    padding: 110px;
    margin-left: -75px;
}

.right-col {
    padding: 86px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 76px;
}

#footer p {
    font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.063em; /*13pt in psd*/
}

#footer .email {
    font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.063em; /*13pt in psd*/
}

#footer .contacts {
    font-size: 1.063em; /*13pt in psd*/
    font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#footer h2 {
    font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.063em; /*13pt in psd*/
    color: #ffffff;
}

#footer a:hover {
    color: #0e6655;
    outline: none;
}

#footer .info {
    font-family: 'GothamMedium', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.5em; /*15pt in psd*/
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.row .md-col-6 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 45px;
}

#footer {
    margin-left: 2%;
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFAcy.jpg):

Comment: apply `position:absolute` and `bottom: 0`

Comment: When i add {position:absolute and bottom: 0} i got this http://postimg.org/image/4zv1wbdk9/ and resized http://s10.postimg.org/r2zhzgg1l/resized.jpg

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle of entire code?

Comment: Yes, of course here you are: https://jsfiddle.net/6116unyr/ . Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

use position fixed..

```
#footer {
    padding: 100px 45px 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

and why u are making your code so lengthy....

```
 #footer p {
    font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.063em; /*13pt in psd*/
}

#footer .email {
    font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.063em; /*13pt in psd*/
}

#footer .contacts {
    font-size: 1.063em; /*13pt in psd*/
    font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#footer h2 {
    font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.063em; /*13pt in psd*/
    color: #ffffff;
}

#footer a:hover {
    color: #0e6655;
    outline: none;
}

#footer .info {
    font-family: 'GothamMedium', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.5em; /*15pt in psd*/
}
```

u can do this...

```
#footer p, #footer .email, #footer .contacts, #footer h2, #footer .info{
    font-family: 'GothamBook', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.063em; /*13pt in psd*/
}
#footer .info {
    font-size: 1.5em; /*15pt in psd*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But when i apply position:fixed i got this http://s10.postimg.org/r2zhzgg1l/resized.jpg . I share my code: https://jsfiddle.net/6116unyr/ maybe it hepls.

Comment: Thank you. But when i add this code what you change i get this problems http://s29.postimg.org/3nukjrldj/Be_pavadinimo.jpg